# Index page does not show inIIS 7.5 fora MVC 3 Web App

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7.5

I have a server with IIS 7.5 and a web application in MVC 3.

When I try to get the index/home for the website I see the Welcome page of IIS instead of my app
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_bCYQxIvMQ2U/TRqMgglKvsI/AAAAAAAAAdk/oh6-o5YpTnE/s320/welcome.png

The problem happen just for the index/home as I am able to get the others pages.

Could you point me out in the right direction? Thanks

In my Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

In web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: Show the code that you have for this index/home view

Answer (score 0):

Create directory in wwwroot directory just for your application and put all files there. Configure application in IIS manager and type in your browser:

```
http://localhost/YOUR_APP_NAME/
```

to retrieve home page of your application. Or simply use 'Browse' menu item in context menu of your application in iis manager tree.

Comment: Then go to your application in IIS manager and select your app in sites tree. Check in Default Website if IIS home page file has higher priority then your home page. If so, then configure Default Website in such a way that your Home Page file has higher priority than IIS one. Maybe simply try to delete IIS home page file, this might could help also.